Morris and Hirsch - $E(Y |X)$ linear function of $X$

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have a joint distribution with
means $μ_X$ and $μ_Y$ , standard deviations $σ_X$ and $σ_Y$ , and
correlation $ρ$. Show that if $E(Y |X)$ is a linear function of
$X$, then


$$E(Y|X) = μ_Y + ρ\frac{σ_Y}{σ_X}(X − μ_X)$$

From $\textit{Morris and Hirsch, $4^{th}$ edition}$
If $E(Y |X)=aX+b$,
$$E(E(Y|X)-E(Y))=0 \implies aE(X)+b=E(Y)$$
Also,
$\begin{align*} 
    &E(XY-XE(Y|X))=0 \\[7pt]
  \iff &    E(XY)=E(X(aX+b)) \\[7pt]
  \iff & E(XY)=aE(X^2)+bE(X)
\end{align*}$
But for this case, how can I show that $\frac{\mu_Y}{\mu_X}=ρ\frac{σ_Y}{σ_X}$?
EDIT:
\begin{align*}
& ρ\frac{σ_Y}{σ_X} 
=\;\frac{σ_{X,Y}}{σ_{X}^2} \\[9 pt]
=\;&\frac{E(XY)-\mu_X\mu_Y}{E(X^2)-E(X)}\\[ 9pt]
=\;&\frac{aE(X^2)+bE(X)-E(X)(aE(X)+b)}{E(X^2)-E(X)}\\[ 9 pt]
=\;&\frac{aE(X^2)-a(E(X))^2}{E(X^2)-E(X)}=a
\end{align*}
And so,
$\begin{align*}
(\ast) \qquad & E(Y|X)-\mu_Y \\[7pt]
=\; & E(Y|X)-(aE(X)+b) \\[7pt]
=\; & aX+b-aE(X)-b \\[7pt]
=\; & a(X-E(X)) \\[7pt]
=\; & ρ\frac{σ_Y}{σ_X}(X-\mu_{x})
\end{align*}$

Hint: $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]$. Also since $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ is a linear function of $X$, you need to assume $\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = aX + b$, not just $aX$.

@geetha290krm, that was the initial hypothesis
